# A locally compact Hausdorff space is compactly generated

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am having trouble showing one direction of the proof that a locally compact Hausdorff space is compactly generated.

Specifically, my question is how do I show that: if X is a locally compact Hausdorff space and A is a subset of X with the property that $$A\cap K$$ is closed for every compact K, then A is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $A$ is not closed, there is a point $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$. Let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$ with compact closure, and let $K=\operatorname{cl}U$. Now consider $K\cap A$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: $K \cap A$ must be closed by hypothesis, Since $x \in cl(A) \setminus A$, there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ converging to x. This sequence is eventually in $U$ as well, since $U$ is an open set containing $x$. Hence $(a_n)$ is eventually in $A \cap U$ and hence in $A \cap K$. But limit of $(a_n)$ is $x$ which is not in $K \cap A$, contradicting that $K \cap A$ is closed. Is this right?

Comment: @eatfood: (I must have been on one of my sabbaticals from MSE when this was asked.) No, because there need not be a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$ unless $X$ is a [Fréchet-Urysohn space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space). Fortunately, we don’t need one: $U\setminus(K\cap A)$ is an open nbhd of $x$, contradicting the fact that $x$ was chosen to be in $\operatorname{cl}A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an element in the complementary of $A$, since $X$ is locally compact, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which has a compact adherence $U'$, $A\cap U'$ is compact thus closed. It implies that $U-A\cap U'$ is open, thus the complementary of $A$ is open. done.

Comment: How do we know that $U-A \cap U' $ is contained in the complement of $A$ ?